# How to set Validation for all controls in a user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I am looking for the best way to set the validation group for all of the controls contained in a user control.  Most of the controls in the control are created dynamically when the control is loaded.  It has quite a few input fields and validators.

I would like to save time by setting the validation for all the controls and validators with some sort of function that could just loop through everything and set it.

It seems though that there is no consistent interface that includes validation group for all of the different controls that have the property.

Should I use reflection to check for Validation group, I know I can do this, but is there a better way?

We are using C# by the way.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT:  I put the answer down below for anyone who wants the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wanted to mark this answered.

Here is the code I used to set the validation group.  I decided to go with using reflection, since I could check types for those I know have ValidationGroup, and cast and set, but there are a lot of types to check, and it could miss new controls that may be added in the future.  Would have been sweet if the ValidationGroup were part of some kind of interface that things had to implement.

```
/// <summary>
/// this is an extension method to iterate though all controls in a control collection
/// put this in some static library somewhere
/// </summary>
/// <param name="controls"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IEnumerable<Control> All(this ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        foreach (Control grandChild in control.Controls.All())
            yield return grandChild;

        yield return control;
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// this function uses reflection to check if the validation group exists, and then set it to the 
/// specified string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ValidationGroup"></param>
private void SetValidationGroup(string ValidationGroup)
{
    //set the validation group for all controls
    if (ValidationGroup.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
    {
        foreach (Control c in Controls.All())
        {
            var Properties = c.GetType().GetProperties();
            var vg = Properties.Where(p => p.Name == "ValidationGroup").SingleOrDefault();
            if (vg != null)
            {
                vg.SetValue(c, ValidationGroup, null);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a very similar problem- the soloution I used was to create a couple of extension methods that could loop over all child/descendent controls of a control, find ones of a particular type and then call a subroutine on them (this subroutine could for example, set any properties of a control). The code is below in VB.Net (sorry this is what we use at work, I'm sure a code translator should be able to sort this out for you).

```
Public Module ControlExtensionMethods

''' <summary>
''' Gets all validation controls used by a control.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="onlyGetVisible">If true, will only fetch validation controls that currently apply (i.e. that are visible). The default value is true.</param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<Extension()>
Public Function GetAllValidationControls(ByVal target As Control, Optional ByVal onlyGetVisible As Boolean = True) As ReadOnlyCollection(Of BaseValidator)
    Dim validators As New List(Of BaseValidator)
    GetControlsOfType(Of BaseValidator)(target, Function(x) Not onlyGetVisible OrElse x.Visible = onlyGetVisible, validators)
    Return validators.AsReadOnly()
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Gets if the control is in a valid state (if all child/descendent validation controls return valid)
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<Extension()>
Public Function IsValid(ByVal target As Control) As Boolean
    Return target.GetAllValidationControls().All(Function(x)
                                                     x.Validate()
                                                     Return x.IsValid
                                                 End Function)
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Iteratively fetches all controls of a specified type/base type from a control and its descendents.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="fromControl"></param>
''' <param name="predicate">If provided, will only return controls that match the provided predicate</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<Extension()>
Public Function GetControlsOfType(Of T As Control)(ByVal fromControl As Control, Optional ByVal predicate As Predicate(Of T) = Nothing) As IList(Of T)
    Dim results As New List(Of T)
    GetControlsOfType(fromControl, predicate, results)
    Return results
End Function

Private Sub GetControlsOfType(Of T As Control)(ByVal fromControl As Control, ByVal predicate As Predicate(Of T), ByVal results As IList(Of T))
    'create default predicate that always returns true if none is provided
    Dim cntrl As Control

    If predicate Is Nothing Then predicate = Function(x) True

    If fromControl.HasControls Then
        For Each cntrl In fromControl.Controls
            GetControlsOfType(Of T)(cntrl, predicate, results)
        Next
    End If

    If TypeOf fromControl Is T AndAlso predicate(fromControl) Then
        results.Add(fromControl)
    End If
End Sub
End Module
```

An example of using this code to disable all validators:

```
Array.ForEach(myUserControl.GetAllValidationControls().ToArray(), sub(x) x.Enabled = False)
```

Comment: That is good,  not quite what I need though.  I think that code only returns a list of Validators, but what I am looking for is everything with a ValidationGroup property, which would include textboxes, buttons, validation summaries and things like that.

Comment: you can specify a predicate in the GetControlsOfType() function so do this: userControl.GetControlsOfType(Of Control)(sub(x) x.ValidationGroup = "myValidationGroup")

Comment: True.  I would have to call the function for every control type that could have a ValidationGroup property, which could potentially be a lot of different types.

Comment: Ah I assumed "ValidationGroup" was inherited from WebControl. In this case, just add a reflection based predicate that would check for the presence of the ValidationGroup property, like so:

userControl.GetControlsOfType(Of Control)(sub(x) x.GetType().GetProperty("ValidationGroup") IsNot Nothing). 
I know you said you were looking for a better way but there really doesn't seem to be one. If you wanted a faster way, you could keep a record of what types you have examined and if they had the ValidationGroup property present- at least this way you could cut down on the expensive GetProperty call.

Answer (score 0):

I was butting my head against this issue just now, and came up with an alternative solution that doesn't involve duck-typing:

```
string newGroup = "foo";
IEnumerable<BaseValidator> validators = this.Controls.OfType<BaseValidator>();
IEnumerable<Button> buttons = this.Controls.OfType<Button>();

foreach (var validator in validators)
    validator.ValidationGroup = newGroup;

foreach (var button in buttons)
    button.ValidationGroup = newGroup;
```

This also might be an alternative:

```
foreach (var c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is BaseValidator)
        (c as BaseValidator).ValidationGroup = newGroup;
    else if (c is Button)
        (c as Button).ValidationGroup = newGroup;
}
```